# Excel - my drop down list contains blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im populating a drop down list from a column on a separate sheet and unwanted blanks are showing up. The column contains the following formula:

=IF(D2="Yes",B2,"")

Excel is treating the result as an empty string and not blank. How do I remove the empty (and blank) values from my drop down list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "Ignore blank" check box next to the List in Data Validation, it worked for me.
(Source: http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/drop-down-list-blank-cells-solved.11184/)

If that is not enough, try to adopt http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-ignore-blanks-in-data-validation-list or http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=159585&s=9a80b245e1dbe68a50131913cc2adda3&p=582541#post582541 for your needs...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ignore blanks doesn't work. I will take a look at your other suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I was not able to replicate your problem 100%, but it seems that http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=159585&s=9a80b245e1dbe68a50131913cc2adda3&p=582541#post582541 was able to solve your problem...